# Loading markers with setintervals and json file

Tags: javascript, google-maps

any solution to load one point at time? Im working with this code but something going wrong when loading
the idea its to load 1 marker with 2s interval to load another one with external .json file.

```
function loadpoints() {

  function getData() {

var min=1;
var max = 4 // max number off json 
var markersArray = [];
var mytime = setInterval(mytime, 2000);

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
var jsonfile = "pointer" + random.toString()+".json" //display one of the files

$.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer) {

  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
      title: ponto.activity,
      icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
      map: map,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });


    console.log("created marker " + marker.position);
  });
  // setTimeout (getData, 10000);
});

};

getData();
//close loadpoints
}
```

Comment: define "something going wrong". Do you get any errors? What does the code do that you didn't expect? What doesn't it do?

Comment: your interval does nothing, how can you load at 2s interval if your create an interval that does absolutely nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will call itself every two seconds with incremented index: https://jsfiddle.net/d5vdzLo6/1/

```
function loadpoints() {

    var min=1;
    var max = 4 // max number off json 
    var markersArray = [];
    var mytime = setInterval(mytime, 2000);

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
    var jsonfile = "pointer" + random.toString()+".json" //display one of the files

    $.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer) {
        drawMarker(pointer, 0)
    });

    function drawMarker(markers, index) {

        if(index >= markers.length) {
            return
        }

        var ponto = markers[index]

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
            title: ponto.activity,
            icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        console.log("created marker " + marker.position);

        setTimeout(function() {
            drawMarker(markers, index + 1)
        }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking in that way but getting error to load the map, i'll put the code im trying to makes works now

Comment: Where are you loading the map? Are you able to put all the markers in at the same time?

Comment: yeah its loading all at the same time, but I'm looking for one pr time

Comment: I added jsfiddle to show that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/d5vdzLo6/1/

Comment: was perfect man! just got some of your code and works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadpoints() {

  function getData() {
    var temp=0;
    var interval= setInterval(function() {

var min=1;
var max = 4 // max number off json 
var markersArray = [];

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
var jsonfile = "pointer" + random.toString()+".json" //display one of the files

$.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer) {

  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
      title: ponto.activity,
      icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    temp++;
    if (temp >pointer.length) clearInterval(interval);

    console.log("created marker " + marker.position);
  }); 
  // setTimeout (getData, 10000);
});

};1000;

getData();
//close loadpoints
}
```

do you know where its is my fault?